# (Etherdelta smart contract) Sending erc20 tokens on behalf of user(depositing to contract) is not working.why?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, metamask, etherdelta

Hi i have copied the etherdelta smart contract code.All is working fine.I can withdraw tokens from the snart contract to my personal wallet. By reading the code what i understand is,the depositToken method is like allowing the contract to send tokens from my wallet on behalf of me.But this is not working.when i click deoosit,the transaction gets reverted. I guess its some issue with the approve() function.Please can someone clear that for me?

```
    function depositToken(address token, uint amount) {
    //remember to call Token(address).approve(this, amount) or this contract will not be able to do the transfer on your behalf.
    if (msg.value>0 || token==0) throw;
    if (!Token(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)) throw;
    tokens[token][msg.sender] = safeAdd(tokens[token][msg.sender], amount);
    Deposit(token, msg.sender, amount, tokens[token][msg.sender]);
  }
```

//remember to call Token(address).approve(this, amount) or this contract will not be able to do the transfer on your behalf.

What this line means?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the `approve` function on the token contract before calling `depositToken`? If you don't, then the `transferFrom` will fail since the contract isn't authorized to move any of your tokens.